# Is it possible to fix the font rendering/font smoothing on Ubuntu 13.04 for Matlab R2013a?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-13.04

Hello everyone I have an issue with the R2013a version of Matlab on Linux. This issue pertains to the awful font rendering when writing scripts in the Matlab Editor. This bad font rendering is not conducive to programming and is a problem when typing code into any other editor on Ubuntu is rendered fine and easy on the eyes. I want the font smoothing to be as nice as it is on both Windows and OSX. I tried selecting the anti-aliasing checkbox and installing high dpi (75 and 100) fonts from the terminal but those did not solve the problem. So what could the issue be? There are a few posts out there that have tried looking for the solution and nothing has been resolved.

Is there anything out there that could really help me with this? I can't do my work properly if this isn't resolved. If there isn't a solution, can someone give a font which doesn't look god awful in matlab editor.

Comment: Did you try the package `matlab-support` for ubuntu?